# How to send tokens from an existing contract to multiple people (will reward with $20 in eth)

Tags: mist, tokens, airdrop

EDIT: This question is not a duplicate. I am asking for someone to walk me through the entire process of distributing my token to multiple individuals. I am entirely new to coding and as such have near-zero clue as to what I am doing. Those other questions/answers are of no help at all. I have read through them and got no where. Please someone help a guy out.

First and foremost I've been doing some digging to try and learn as much as I can and there are already a number of threads that address a similair question in part. But having no background in coding/solidity etc I have no clue what I'm doing. So if anyone of you guys would be willing to, I'd love it if someone could fill me in step by step exactly how I need to go about solving the problem.

As the title suggests I'm fairly new to solidity and coding in general and as such i seem to be having a ton of difficulty figuring this stuff out. But my question is how do I implement a smart contract or something of the like that would then allow me to send a fixed amount of tokens that I have already created to x people at once.

Please help a brotha out lol.

Comment: You need the address of every person that you want to send tokens to. You can save that in array and iterate over it and use transfer() to send it tokens.

Comment: What do you mean save it in array and iterate over it? Can you tell me step by step how to do it in mist?

Comment: Ill reward whoever can get this working for me with $20 in eth

Comment: Do you have a list of addresses that you want to send ether to?

Comment: Yes I do, I just need a way to send tokens from an existing contract to all of the addresses quickly and efficiently.